# JavaScript tabs works only when an individual tab is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple tabs widget, here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3eRn/1/

When I add another Tabs widget "as you will see in the example" in the same page, everything get missed up! I really don't know how to describe it... after looking into it and trying to debug it, I have concluded that it is the JavaScript that needs to be looked at, so I have researched, but didn't really find an answer that would fix it. However, I found that using `.each` might fix it? so I did try it but didn't work - maybe I used it wrong.

What I am doing wrong? 
Here is the JS:

```
//Tabs Navigation
    $('.tabs .tabs-menu a:eq(0)').addClass('active');    
    $('.tabs .tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)').hide();
    $('.tabs .tabs-menu a').on('click', function() {
        $('.tabs-menu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.tabs .tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure only the current tab group is being affected (using `.each`):

http://jsfiddle.net/G3eRn/2/

```
//Tabs Navigation
$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var $tabs = $(this);
    $tabs.find('.tabs-menu a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    $tabs.find('.tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)').hide();
    $tabs.find('.tabs-menu a').on('click', function () {
        $tabs.find('.tabs-menu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $tabs.find('.tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

And here's a version that's a little more performant:

http://jsfiddle.net/G3eRn/7/

```
//Tabs Navigation
$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var $tabs = $(this);
    $tabs.find('.tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)').hide().end()
         .find('.tabs-menu a').on('click', function () {
             $tabs.find('.tabs-menu a').removeClass('active').end()
             .find('.tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
             $(this).addClass('active');
    }).eq(0).addClass('active');
});
```

The second example uses [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) which "undoes" the last selector.
So for example

```
$('.el').find('div').end().addClass('test')
```

would add the class "test" to the `.el` element instead of all div's inside it.

Comment: Can you paste it here? so I can compare it and select it as an answer?

Comment: May I ask, what is .end()? and why do you have two in .eq(0).addClass('active').end().end()

Comment: That's because I copied it to quickly ;) I've added an explanation of `end()` to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I have tried to do what you have done here to fix another accordion tabs! but I am failing miserably! I did exactly like you did here, and it is very similar but didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/vB4N2/ please can you show me what you did? why isn't working with the other example

Comment: You simply forgot to include jquery. Also right now only one `.accordian-body` is visible among all accordion groups. If you want to allow one per group you need to change the first line of the click event handler.

Comment: That depends on what you want. Currently you have two accordion groups and clicking on any header closes all other bodies on ALL groups. If that's what you want then you did it right. Otherwise (if you want Section A of the first group and Section B of the second group open at the same time) you'd need do change the line I mentioned.

Comment: But what do I need to do with that line?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the functions to every `.tabs` element.

```
$('.tabs').each(function() {
    var $tabs = $(this);

    $('.tabs-menu a:eq(0)', $tabs).addClass('active');    
    $('.tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)', $tabs).hide();
    $('.tabs-menu a', $tabs).on('click', function() {
        $('.tabs-menu a', $tabs).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')', $tabs).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

The syntax `jQuery( 'selector', node )` selects child elements only inside the given HTML element node. In this case an element with the class `.tabs`. This is similar to do `jQuery( node ).find( 'selector' )`.

Using `$` is just a way for me to always know, which variable is a jQuery object. For example: `var $this = jQuery( this );`.

If you want more performance in your script store selected node in a variable (e.g. `.tabs-menu a` in your code). You may even `querySelector` to get the elements via plain JS instead of jQuery. The jQuery `each` on the other hand is very comfortable.

An example mixup of different methods:

```
$('.tabs').each(function() {
    var tabs = this,
    links = this.querySelectorAll( '.tabs-menu a' );

    /* passing a DOMNodeList to jQuery and filter it */
    $(links).filter(':eq(0)', tabs).addClass('active');    
    $('.tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)', tabs).hide();

    /* setup event handler */

    /* without jQuery, one need to itererate over the list of elements */
    for( var i = links.length; i--; ) {
        var currentLink = links[i];
        currentLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var currentTab = this;

            /* jQuery does the loop internally */
            $(links).removeClass('active');
            currentTab.classList.add('active');

            $('.tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(currentTab).index() + ')', tabs).show().siblings().hide();
        }, false);
    }
});
```

For documentation and browser support see here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

There is a JS ployfill for nearly any modern feature:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Comment: @Leo And what errors did you get in the browser console?

Comment: @Leo If I paste that code into your jsFiddle the tabs work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/G3eRn/4/

Comment: The problem is in the last line of the click handler. Simply removing the ".tabs" at the beginning of the selector fixes it

Answer (score 1):

In your "click" handler, you have to make sure that you're applying changes only to the relevant group of tabs. As your code is currently written, the handler code will affect *all* the matching tab groups on the page.

You can use jQuery DOM navigation methods to do it:

```
$('.tabs .tabs-menu a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
$('.tabs .tabs-sections .tabs-section:not(:first-child)').hide();

$('.tabs .tabs-menu a').on('click', function () {
    // find the current menu group and deactivate all tab labels
    $(this).closest('.tabs-menu').find('a').removeClass('active');
    // activate this tab
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // find the tab section corresponding to this tab menu
    $(this).closest('.tabs').find('.tabs-sections > .tabs-section:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

The `.closest()` method walks up the DOM looking for a match. From that point, `.find()` looks *down* the DOM in that isolated subtree.

[Here's your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/dLm7X/)

Personally I'd use a delegated handler setup so that tab groups could be added dynamically without needing to re-run the code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tabs-menu a', function() {
  // as above
});
```

Comment: It worked, however the div's are all shown by default

Comment: @Leo did you look at the fiddle I linked? The code posted here doesn't include the first two lines from your fiddle. They're still important!

Comment: Please update it here, as I just tried it with the old code but didn't work

Comment: @Leo ok, pasted the two lines in from the fiddle.